# Does one "Write" with a Computer?

Tags: word-choice

We usually say that we 'write a column in newspaper' but if it's related to computer and all what do we use then? Do we say 'creating a column' instead? 
For example if we have to fill in a blank like 'It takes time to ***_*** a witty column' what should we fill in?

Comment: Why do we still dial a phone number?

Comment: Why do we say things in written contexts (comments on ELU, for example) such as *"What I'm **saying** is [blah blah]"*, when obviously we're ***talking*** about what we're ***writing***?

Comment: Whatever, but don't use _create_: it's used way too often nowadays, even when more appropriate verbs are available.

Answer (score 5):

We still call it writing, whether it it written, printed, scribbled, or typed. And the person writing it is still a writer.

The word "write" encompasses any mechanism where words and sentences *can* end up on the printed page. Even an author who dictates his or her work is still a writer.